# My name is the same as my nationality

Tags: riddle, knowledge, sports

My name is the same as my nationality. I was considered as one of the best in my sport, but I never scored. Who am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> Petr Cech - a former goalkeeper from Czech

Comment: You got it! That was very quick.

Comment: So we're not counting own goals? :-)

Comment: [Here he is scoring brilliantly!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HM2lywQKC_M) T_T

Comment: Haha I forgot about own goals.

Comment: Two Scotts who (briefly) kept goal for Scotland, but most likely don't qualify as best in their country, let alone the world! [Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Fox) and [Bain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Bain).